# Pass a configuration to an intent in a widget that uses AppIntentConfiguration

Tags: ios, swift, widgetkit

I have 2 WidgetKit widgets that are created using an `AppIntentConfiguration`:

```
var body: some WidgetConfiguration {
    AppIntentConfiguration(kind: kind, intent: SelectValueTrackerIntent.self, provider: TrackerTimelineProvider(trackerType: .value)) { entry in
        TracKitWidgetEntryView(timelineEntry: entry)
            .containerBackground(Color.tk_mainBackgroundColor, for: .widget)
    }
    .configurationDisplayName("My Widget")
    .description("This is an example widget.")
}
```

Each widget uses an intent to provide widget configuration with dynamic values. Both widgets fetch the same data via the network, but each one of them filters the data slightly differently to provide a different list of possible values.

I haven't been able to find a way to make this setup work without duplicating all the code used for the app intent.

Here's the rest of the code used:

```
struct SelectValueTrackerIntent: WidgetConfigurationIntent {
    static var title: LocalizedStringResource = "Select Tracker"
    static var description = IntentDescription("Selects the tracker to display information for.")

    @Parameter(title: "Tracker")
    var tracker: ValueTrackerAppEntity
}

struct ValueTrackerAppEntity: AppEntity {
    static var defaultQuery = ValueTrackerQuery()
    static var typeDisplayRepresentation: TypeDisplayRepresentation = "Tracker"
    
    var displayRepresentation: DisplayRepresentation {
        DisplayRepresentation(title: "\(title)")
    }
    
    var id: String
    let title: String
}

struct ValueTrackerQuery: EntityQuery {
    func entities(for identifiers: [String]) async throws -> [ValueTrackerAppEntity] {
        return try await entitiesForAllTrackers().filter {
            identifiers.contains($0.id)
        }
    }

    func suggestedEntities() async throws -> [ValueTrackerAppEntity] {
        return try await entitiesForAllTrackers()
    }
    
    func defaultResult() async -> ValueTrackerAppEntity? {
        if let tracker = try? await entitiesForAllTrackers().first {
            return tracker
        }
    
        return nil
    }
}
```

Is there a way of being able to pass a configuration parameter to `SelectValueTrackerIntent`, `ValueTrackerAppEntity` or `ValueTrackerQuery` to be able to provide different data, given that `WidgetConfigurationIntent` and `AppEntity` are initialized internally by WidgetKit?